# Show custom field value in cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress together with WooCommerce for my shop.
I want to output the value of my custom field in my cart and in the email order confirmation.

I have created a custom field in my functions.php:

```
// Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div class="options_group">';

// Input
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'                => '_gram', 
        'label'             => __( 'somelabel', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder'       => '', 
        'description'       => __( 'sometext', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'              => 'number', 
        'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step'  => 'any',
                'min'   => '0'
            ) 
    )
);

  echo '</div>';

}

function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
    // Number Field
    $woocommerce_number_field = $_POST['_gram'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_number_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_gram', esc_attr( $woocommerce_number_field ) );

}
```

On my pages I'm using:

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_gram', true );
```

To show the value and that work perfect.

Now I want to show this same value under the product name in my cart and in the email confirmations.
But I cant figure out how to do this.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: woocommerce cart works on session so you also need to store this value in cart and then get the value from cart session on cart page and the follow the next process.

Comment: What is the id you get there, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's a long process, you have to implement two filters & one action to accomplish this.

Also there is a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/) for this exact purpose along with lot of other options related to woocommerce custom fields.

Here is the direct solution for your question.

```
/**
 * Here we are trying to add your custom data as Cart Line Item
 * SO that we can add this custom data on your cart, checkout, order and email later
 */
function save_custom_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    $custom_data = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_gram', true );
    if( $custom_data != null && $custom_data != ""  ) {
        $cart_item_data["gram"] = $custom_data;
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_data', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Here we are trying to display that custom data on Cart Table & Checkout Order Review Table 
 */
function render_custom_data_on_cart_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item = null ) {
    $custom_items = array();
    /* Woo 2.4.2 updates */
    if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) {
        $custom_items = $cart_data;
    }
    if( isset( $cart_item["gram"] ) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( "name" => "Gram", "value" => $cart_item["gram"] );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'render_custom_data_on_cart_checkout', 10, 2 );

/**
 * We are adding that custom data ( gram ) as Order Item Meta, 
 * which will be carried over to EMail as well 
 */
function save_custom_order_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset( $values["gram"] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "Gram", $values["gram"] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'save_custom_order_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: The function is working.
Do you know how to use/show one more custom field?